# Best jquery form wizard for a rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need a multistep registration form wizard for my rails app.. I know theres lots of established jquery solutions out there, anyone have an opinion on the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this video tutorial from [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/)

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Also look at:

- [Turn any webform into a powerful wizard with jQuery (FormToWizard plugin)](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx)
- [Demo](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/webform_to_wizard/)