# Rails - Dividing a Devise Form into separate tabs and submit with one button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Apologies for the question, I'm still learning rails. Trying to separate my edit rails devise form into separate tabs in the same page with a single update button. A user can then switch between tabs and when ready he or she can press update. I've already managed to get my view to look correct, but whenever a person clicks update nothing happens. I've provided my relevant code below. Thank you so much.

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="tabbable-panel">
   <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="trending71" class="tab-pane fade in active"><br>
    <div class="col-md-5">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :avatar, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %><br />
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :background, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <%= f.file_field :background %><br />
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
   </div>
  </div>
 <div id="fire" class="tab-pane fade">
  <br>
  <div class="col-md-5">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :homecity %><br>
     <%= f.collection_select :homecity_id, Homecity.all, :id, :Hometown %>
    <div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="essos" class="tab-pane fade">
  <br>
  <div class="col-md-5">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <h2>Cancel my account</h2>
   <p>Unhappy?
   <br>
   <br>
   <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), class: "btn btn-danger", data: { confirm: "Are you sure? You cannot undo this." }, method: :delete %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary' %>
</div>
<% end %>
<div>
```

[image]

Comment: You have a serious indentation problem.

Comment: Sebastian I know i was trying to fix it several times (I spent like 30 mins trying) but SO kept on giving me trouble

Comment: Ref link: https://medium.com/@nicolasblanco/developing-a-wizard-or-multi-steps-forms-in-rails-d2f3b7c692ce

https://github.com/nicolasblanco/wizard_app or by using jquery 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613244/best-jquery-form-wizard-for-a-rails-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sebastian was referring to your actual code, not just the SO version. Try to look into your indentation more carefully. This should work:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="tabbable-panel">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="trending71" class="tab-pane fade in active"><br>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :avatar, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
            <%= f.file_field :avatar %><br />
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :background, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <%= f.file_field :background %><br />
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="fire" class="tab-pane fade">
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :homecity %><br>
              <%= f.collection_select :homecity_id, Homecity.all, :id, :Hometown %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="essos" class="tab-pane fade">
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5">
          <h2>Cancel my account</h2>
          <p>Unhappy?
          <br>
          <br>
          <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), class: "btn btn-danger", data: { confirm: "Are you sure? You cannot undo this." }, method: :delete %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Wrong indentation most times causes html to look really messy. In your case you probably didn't notice because the page was simple or it just didn't mess it up visually. In any case once the html loads in the browser, the browser will automatically close all pending tags. That means that your form tag probably closed before the button tag or something like this, so the button was not a part of the form anymore.

I also tweaked bootstrap columns a bit. You can use col-md-offset-5 instead of putting an empty div with col-md-5 class. Keeps your code shorter. You might also want to use the "row" class to separate rows (so you can get rid of the empty col-md-3 divs). I would suggest you take another look at bootstrap grid system. Good luck!